# Retrieving data from Model while doing a Kendo grid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

This is the Model Code:

```
namespace WEB02.Models
{
public class GridDatatable
{

    public DataTable Table { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is View code including the kendo grid:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model WEB02.Models.GridDatatable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
   <h2>Index</h2>
   <div id="divGrid">

  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
.Name("TTGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn c in Model.Table.Columns)
    {
        columns.Bound(c.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("String");
    }
  })
.Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(10))
.Sortable(sortable => sortable
        .AllowUnsort(true)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))

  .Editable(editable => editable.Enabled(true)
  .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))

.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        //Define the model
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Table.Columns)
        {
            model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
            model.Id("Id");
        }
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("griddata", "Configuration"))

)

    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)

        .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 })
        .ButtonCount(10)
    )
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
  )
</div>
```

The controller code:

```
    namespace WEB02.Controllers
{
public class ConfigurationController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Configuration/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GridDatatable gridTable = new GridDatatable();
        gridTable.Table = new DataTable();
        gridTable.Table.Columns.Add("Name");
        return View("Index",gridTable);
    }

    public ActionResult _WorkflowPartial()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult griddata([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        GridDatatable gridTable = new GridDatatable();
        gridTable.Table = new DataTable();
        gridTable.Table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        List<string> Griddetails;
        Griddetails = RxMUaClient.Browse("2", "127.0.0.1:48030", "Mls.Work.Triggers");
        gridTable.Table = ConvertListToDataTable(Griddetails);       
        if (request.Aggregates.Any())
        {
            request.Aggregates.Each(agg => agg.Aggregates.Each(a =>
            {
                a.MemberType = gridTable.Table.Columns[agg.Member].DataType;
            }));
        }
        return Json(gridTable.Table.ToDataSourceResult(request));

    }
    static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string> list)
    {
        // New table.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Name");

        int rows = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rows - 1; i++)
        {

            table.Rows.Add(list[i]);
        }

        return table;
    }


}
}
```

When i try to browse the URl /Configuration/Index 
i get an error in the Model as if the Model is not available in the Models folder even that it is already done.

I also have some problem calling a view from the controller by browsing it on the browser, it gives an error that this view is not available in the folder, while i already done the view and connected it to the ActionResult method in the controller.

I amnot able to post the screenshot of the error as i have to have more that 10 stupid points!!!! 
Anyway the error was

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'GridDatatable' does not exist in the namespace 'WEB02.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 38:
Line 39:
Line 40:     public class _Page_Views_Configuration_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {
Line 41:
Line 42: #line hidden

Source File: c:\Users\ABK1LO\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\b7cd7403\dfc9d84e\App_Web_index.cshtml.edf51036.0r4hbktj.0.cs    Line: 40

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

Comment: So I am assuming you are trying to bind to a `DataTable` due to some form of dynamic column set up (again assuming this is going to be used as a generic `control` *for want of a better word*) Do any of your column names have spaces in them at all? Also how is the model being initialized for the page. Can you provide the controller code for the Index and read actions.

Comment: @DavidShorthose 
No the columns names have no space and i am only dealing with one column.

I added the code for the controller in the code.
Thanks

Comment: first thing that pops out is this ` model.Id("Id");` remove it from your column set up if you don't have a column called `id` in your dataset this could be throwing an error.

Comment: upvoted so you can post that screenshoot the next time!

Comment: @ThomasKoelle thanks :D

Comment: @DavidShorthose it appeared that the problem was with the run of the solution it self as there was a file missing. but now the my problem is that the grid does not give me any error but it does not appear on the screen as well!!

Comment: Can you provide the section of your layout page that is including the css, js files and what version of the `Kendo.MVC.dll` are you using. Alternatively if you have a copy of the project that you can share I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: @DavidShorthose ...It worked.. thanks for your help but i had to modify the model and to re do it for the grid, that was the reason it was not working. Again thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was passing an the model to the view and forming the columns of the grid with the model, then fetching the data by the datasource read from the method in the controller.

The kendo grid view was as following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
.Name("StatusGrid")
//.HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:50%;" })
.Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn c in Model.GridStatus.Columns)
    {
        columns.Bound(c.ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("String");
    }
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.GridStatus.Columns)
        {
            model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
            model.Id("Id");
        }
    })
    .Read(read =>

        read.Action("StatusGeneric", "Configuration")
    )
))
```